# Update pattern for mapping graticule

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a map with some geojson and a graticule.

The geojson is added to the map correctly, but I can not get the graticule added using the standard d3 update, enter, exit procedure.  The graticule is correctly added when I just append it however.  I don't fully understand the role of the attr "d", so possibly that is where the problem is?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
update = function(map){

var projection = d3.geo.satellite()
  .distance(projParams["distance"])
  .scale(projParams["scale"])
  .rotate([projParams["rotateLong"], projParams["rotateLat"], projParams["rotateZ"]])
  .center([projParams["centerX"], projParams["centerY"]])
  .tilt(projParams["tilt"])
  .clipAngle(Math.acos(1 / 1.1) * 180 / Math.PI - 1e-6)
  .precision(1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

// create california shape

var mapElement = svg.selectAll(".boundary")
  .data(map.features)
  .attr("d", path);

mapElement.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "boundary")
  .attr("d", path)

mapElement.exit().remove();


// create graticule shape

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
    .extent([[-130.4183, 35], [-47 + 1e-6, 57 + 1e-6]])
    .step([.1, .1]);

var graticuleElement = svg.selectAll(".graticule")
  .data(graticule)
  .attr("d", path);

graticuleElement.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "graticule")
  .attr("d", path)

graticuleElement.exit().remove();


// working graticule code without update ability 

// grid = svg.append("path")
// .datum(graticule)
// .attr("class", "graticule")
// .attr("d", path);}
```

Comment: It's just a single datum, so you don't have selections as such. Update by selecting the existing element, binding new data and calling `.attr("d", path)` again -- `grid.datum(graticule).attr("d", path)`

Comment: Thanks Lars!  This works, but could you explain why the enter selection does not work with the graticule?  Shouldn't the single "graticule" data element still appear in the enter selection?  What am I missing?

Comment: D3 computes selections over multiple data elements. You have just a single one. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) for more detail.